# Proof of Theorem (average of a function over the surface a ball)

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

Could I please some explanation regarding this proof. 
I understand everything up to the “we conclude that…”

> (Average of a function over the surface of a ball). Let $g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $\boldsymbol{x}_{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} .$ Then
> $$
> ⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})} g(\boldsymbol{z}) d S(\boldsymbol{z}) \rightarrow g(\boldsymbol{x}_{0}) \quad \text { as } \quad \varepsilon \rightarrow 0
> $$
>
> Proof. We prove the lemma under the stronger assumption that $g$ is continuously differentiable, which is sufficient for our purposes. Observe that
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \left|⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})} g(\boldsymbol{z}) d S(\boldsymbol{z})-g(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})\right| &=\left|⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})}(g(\boldsymbol{z})-g(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})) d S(\boldsymbol{z})\right| \\
> & \leq ⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})}\left|g(\boldsymbol{z})-g(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})\right| d S(\boldsymbol{z})
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the Chain Rule
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \left|g(\boldsymbol{z})-g(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})\right| &=\left|\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d}{d t} g((1-t) \boldsymbol{x}_{0}+t \boldsymbol{z}) d t\right| \\
> &=\left|\int_{0}^{1} \nabla g((1-t) \boldsymbol{x}_{0}+t \boldsymbol{z}) \cdot(\boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{x}_{0}) d t\right| \\
> & \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left|\nabla g((1-t) \boldsymbol{x}_{0}+t \boldsymbol{z}) \| \boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{x}_{0}\right| d t \\
> & \leq \max _{l(\boldsymbol{x}_{0}, \boldsymbol{z})}|\nabla g|\left|\boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{x}_{0}\right|
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where $l(\boldsymbol{x}_{0}, \boldsymbol{z})$ is the line joining $\boldsymbol{x}_{0}$ to $\boldsymbol{z}$. Let $\varepsilon<1$ and let
> $$
> M:=\max _{B_{1}(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})}|\nabla g|
> $$
> We conclude that
> $$
> \left|⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})} g(\boldsymbol{z}) d S(\boldsymbol{z})-g(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})\right| \leq ⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\boldsymbol{x}_{0})} M\left|\boldsymbol{z}-\boldsymbol{x}_{0}\right| d S(\boldsymbol{z})=M \varepsilon \rightarrow 0 \text { as } \varepsilon \rightarrow 0
> $$
> as required.

Comment: As to your choice of tags: this has nothing to do with function analysis nor partial differential equations.

Comment: @daw I didn't mean to add functional analysis but I disagree wrt to PDEs. This is literally in my PDEs lecture notes and is a necessary result used in the proof of possoin's equation's solution.

Comment: The notes where this is from has no relevance here. The question is self-contained and its content has nothing to do with PDEs.

Comment: @IsaacBullock I agree. I think **nothing** is a stretch. The moment I saw this, I thought about the fundamental solution of Poisson's and the solution obtained from the radial solution of Laplace's. I first encountered this theorem in Evans book which is titled Partial Differential Equations; so having nothing to do with PDEs is simply not true. 
But there tends to be a sect of keyboard police on this site so I would oblige to keep the peace. Especially as you already have a very good answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is as follows. Using the fact that
$$
|g(\mathbf z) - g(\mathbf x_0)| \leq M |\mathbf z - \mathbf x_0|, 
$$
we have
\begin{align}
\left|⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\mathbf x_0)} g(\mathbf z) dS(\mathbf z) - g(\mathbf x_0) \right|
& \leq
⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\mathbf x_0)} |g(\mathbf z) - g(\mathbf x_0)|dS 
\\ & \leq 
⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\mathbf x_0)} M \cdot |\mathbf z - \mathbf x_0|dS 
\\ & = 
⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\mathbf x_0)} M \epsilon\, dS
\\ & 
= M\epsilon \cdot ⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\mathbf x_0)}  1\, dS.
\end{align}

The barred integral $⨍$ means that we divide the integral by the area of the sphere. Thus, $⨍_{\partial B_{\epsilon}(\mathbf x_0)}  1\, dS = 1$.

Comment: If you read closely, the integral is crossed out which means average, we divide it by measure of the boundary of the ball. The surface measure doesn't have to be normed here

Comment: @Jakobian I wasn't sure how to interpret the bar. Thanks for clearing that up

Comment: For typing it in Mathjax, the only solution I know is to use the unicode character e.g. `$$⨍_MdS$$` gives $$⨍_MdS$$
(the LaTeX package `unicode-math` provides `\intbar`)

Comment: @Calvin Thanks!